# IBM MQ Error Code 2397 using java SSL

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to set up a 2 way SSl using my java code. I am successful doing it one way that is server certificate gets validated from my side but when it comes to two way I get a 2397 Error code.

Steps followed by me are:

1. Create a keystore with a self-signed certificate using Keytool, deploy it in truststore of MQ server.
2. Create a keystore for MQ server and create a self-signed certificate.
3. Deploy MQ server's certificate in my truststore.

Then I try to run my java Code.  This works fine without SSL or One way SSL.But two way handshake if failing.  Below is the code and stack trace:

```
    //code to create MQ connectivity
    public static void main(String [] args){
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");
    //keystore path
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/keystores/keystore.jks");              
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
    //trsutstore path
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/keystores/truststore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
    //cipher spec          
     MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5";
     MQEnvironment.hostname = "*****-ws3717";//system name
     MQEnvironment.port = 1414;
     MQEnvironment.channel = "channel_name";//channel name
     MQQueueManager qm = null;
     try {  qm = new MQQueueManager("QMNGR");
         System.out.println("Conn Successs!!!");
     } catch (MQException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     finally {
         try {
             qm.disconnect();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             e.getCause();
         }
     }
     } }
```

Stack Trace is as follows:

```
keyStore is : C:/keystores/keystore.jks
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
***
found key for : selfsigned
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 132473562370742919150140985227175013875110053845431438145351913928668686945002725183702560702247749924970161010103451411451345824467592557656888776558245848713650717773344294766986771753500118311618188922138349812131167438364266468003061810102502957510761089213138803410346480285664890149111581898928681089463
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri May 25 13:54:00 IST 2012,
               To: Sat May 25 13:54:00 IST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  SerialNumber: [    4fbf41a0]
]
  Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 46 D0 CC DF AB 5F 6F D3   37 33 E1 64 F7 1B F7 3F  F...._o.73.d...?
0010: 98 95 06 09 F9 84 C8 3A   65 CF A7 24 BB 46 95 DF  .......:e..$.F..
0020: 8B 30 F2 BC 5C F9 CC 31   E4 36 53 43 BB 50 1B EF  .0..\..1.6SC.P..
0030: 8C 9B DB C0 41 C9 2C 37   AD B6 1D 30 BF 6E 75 E4  ....A.,7...0.nu.
0040: A9 05 E7 30 5A B1 30 84   6B 8E B7 7A 83 2D 33 01  ...0Z.0.k..z.-3.
0050: A1 44 86 A0 11 30 C3 4D   5B 68 7E 0B 09 48 03 CC  .D...0.M[h...H..
0060: DF C5 97 AD 87 40 DC 2A   9A 3D ED FC 27 D3 8B 4F  .....@.*.=..'..O
0070: F0 21 02 E8 62 6B 05 63   57 BB E8 4D 33 EA 35 9E  .!..bk.cW..M3.5.
]
***
trustStore is: C:\keystores\truststore.jks
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  Issuer:  CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4fbf4261
  Valid from Fri May 25 13:57:13 IST 2012 until Sat May 25 13:57:13 IST 2013
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, SSLv3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1321485794 bytes = { 138, 193, 95, 113, 86, 252, 250, 50, 154, 121, 73, 8, 93, 116, 115, 184, 182, 142, 240, 205, 15, 250, 172, 171, 111, 5, 122, 52 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 52
main, READ: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 4875
*** ServerHello, SSLv3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1321485794 bytes = { 250, 173, 248, 90, 241, 136, 107, 119, 99, 92, 80, 19, 223, 223, 152, 131, 216, 115, 242, 56, 198, 135, 156, 111, 210, 234, 220, 103 }
Session ID:  {240, 31, 0, 0, 80, 56, 194, 89, 112, 238, 203, 154, 79, 75, 68, 48, 106, 203, 19, 130, 88, 88, 88, 88, 226, 70, 196, 79, 13, 0, 0, 0}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
Compression Method: 0
***
Warning: No renegotiation indication extension in ServerHello
%% Created:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 105605049659295333895264877648371480987144339115417104117025065956957634413900327625548229515098843172709660865042903412409581107015480309223474293490705595126088958625491899627683399717294708677347640098462040771799700233921554682196524988217754821345297656825451441457385676164016790486091736694366149540953
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri May 25 13:57:13 IST 2012,
               To: Sat May 25 13:57:13 IST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  SerialNumber: [    4fbf4261]
]
  Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 81 F5 2C 2A 77 63 F1 CD   D8 31 E1 BE B5 9B 28 C5  ..,*wc...1....(.
0010: 6B EA 24 BB 5C 3D EB D0   EB E3 86 2E D7 1C 0D 92  k.$.\=..........
0020: 36 A2 79 13 BC 74 40 C4   BF 7C F7 1B 05 8C 6B CF  6.y..t@.......k.
0030: EB 2C C2 0D E3 40 F7 F0   95 66 B6 85 AE 84 66 C9  .,...@...f....f.
0040: B7 C5 29 BE 71 1F 28 C0   83 1C 94 41 08 2A 44 45  ..).q.(....A.*DE
0050: 99 FD C5 77 28 26 FC 50   A3 69 32 BD F5 8B 0C A6  ...w(&.P.i2.....
0060: 13 21 0F BA B2 C6 A2 71   18 17 94 31 3B 7E 88 63  .!.....q...1;..c
0070: C0 01 76 DC 60 47 BB 3F   2F 7E 2A 73 84 DA 60 79  ..v.`G.?/.*s..`y
]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 105605049659295333895264877648371480987144339115417104117025065956957634413900327625548229515098843172709660865042903412409581107015480309223474293490705595126088958625491899627683399717294708677347640098462040771799700233921554682196524988217754821345297656825451441457385676164016790486091736694366149540953
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri May 25 13:57:13 IST 2012,
               To: Sat May 25 13:57:13 IST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  SerialNumber: [    4fbf4261]
]
  Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 81 F5 2C 2A 77 63 F1 CD   D8 31 E1 BE B5 9B 28 C5  ..,*wc...1....(.
0010: 6B EA 24 BB 5C 3D EB D0   EB E3 86 2E D7 1C 0D 92  k.$.\=..........
0020: 36 A2 79 13 BC 74 40 C4   BF 7C F7 1B 05 8C 6B CF  6.y..t@.......k.
0030: EB 2C C2 0D E3 40 F7 F0   95 66 B6 85 AE 84 66 C9  .,...@...f....f.
0040: B7 C5 29 BE 71 1F 28 C0   83 1C 94 41 08 2A 44 45  ..).q.(....A.*DE
0050: 99 FD C5 77 28 26 FC 50   A3 69 32 BD F5 8B 0C A6  ...w(&.P.i2.....
0060: 13 21 0F BA B2 C6 A2 71   18 17 94 31 3B 7E 88 63  .!.....q...1;..c
0070: C0 01 76 DC 60 47 BB 3F   2F 7E 2A 73 84 DA 60 79  ..v.`G.?/.*s..`y
]
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=server-certs@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Server CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting cc, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA>
<EMAILADDRESS=premium-server@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Premium Server CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting cc, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA>
<EMAILADDRESS=personal-basic@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Personal Basic CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA>
<EMAILADDRESS=personal-freemail@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Personal Freemail CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA>
<EMAILADDRESS=personal-premium@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Personal Premium CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting, L=Cape Town, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA>
<CN=VeriSign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=VeriSign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=VeriSign Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3, OU="(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU="(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Class 4 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<OU=Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<OU=Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05, OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority, OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net, C=US>
<CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048), OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net>
<CN=Entrust.net Client Certification Authority, OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/Client_CA_Info/CPS incorp. by ref. limits liab., O=Entrust.net, C=US>
<CN=Entrust.net Client Certification Authority, OU=(c) 2000 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/GCCA_CPS incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net>
<CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority, OU=(c) 2000 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/SSL_CPS incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net>
<CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN>
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: selfsigned
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 132473562370742919150140985227175013875110053845431438145351913928668686945002725183702560702247749924970161010103451411451345824467592557656888776558245848713650717773344294766986771753500118311618188922138349812131167438364266468003061810102502957510761089213138803410346480285664890149111581898928681089463
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri May 25 13:54:00 IST 2012,
               To: Sat May 25 13:54:00 IST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=Pooja Joshi, OU=SGW, O=SUNGARD, L=PUNE, ST=MH, C=IN
  SerialNumber: [    4fbf41a0]
]
  Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 46 D0 CC DF AB 5F 6F D3   37 33 E1 64 F7 1B F7 3F  F...._o.73.d...?
0010: 98 95 06 09 F9 84 C8 3A   65 CF A7 24 BB 46 95 DF  .......:e..$.F..
0020: 8B 30 F2 BC 5C F9 CC 31   E4 36 53 43 BB 50 1B EF  .0..\..1.6SC.P..
0030: 8C 9B DB C0 41 C9 2C 37   AD B6 1D 30 BF 6E 75 E4  ....A.,7...0.nu.
0040: A9 05 E7 30 5A B1 30 84   6B 8E B7 7A 83 2D 33 01  ...0Z.0.k..z.-3.
0050: A1 44 86 A0 11 30 C3 4D   5B 68 7E 0B 09 48 03 CC  .D...0.M[h...H..
0060: DF C5 97 AD 87 40 DC 2A   9A 3D ED FC 27 D3 8B 4F  .....@.*.=..'..O
0070: F0 21 02 E8 62 6B 05 63   57 BB E8 4D 33 EA 35 9E  .!..bk.cW..M3.5.
]
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, SSLv3
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 711
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 00 3D 04 C8 EF 08 83   A4 EF 85 1C D9 96 A0 77  ..=............w
0010: 32 2A A5 43 14 98 11 6F   DD 01 52 73 4D DF B4 5A  2*.C...o..RsM..Z
0020: C5 2E FC 2A C0 F6 C2 9B   11 23 B2 C0 7B 59 E8 96  ...*.....#...Y..
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 4F C4 46 E2 8A C1 5F 71   56 FC FA 32 9A 79 49 08  O.F..._qV..2.yI.
0010: 5D 74 73 B8 B6 8E F0 CD   0F FA AC AB 6F 05 7A 34  ]ts.........o.z4
Server Nonce:
0000: 4F C4 46 E2 FA AD F8 5A   F1 88 6B 77 63 5C 50 13  O.F....Z..kwc\P.
0010: DF DF 98 83 D8 73 F2 38   C6 87 9C 6F D2 EA DC 67  .....s.8...o...g
Master Secret:
0000: C0 20 A8 BC D1 A7 06 B0   C5 07 CA A7 83 C5 35 9E  . ............5.
0010: 20 AB B6 28 8C 7E EF 14   CB 9D C1 ED C5 62 F8 A1   ..(.........b..
0020: 6A DE 9F AF 16 5B 2F 1D   21 8F A3 2C F7 B9 3D 36  j....[/.!..,..=6
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 09 E8 CE 6C D1 2D 43 86   7E 74 1C 5F 68 DA E2 AE  ...l.-C..t._h...
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: CE 62 DA F7 2C F2 2B 4A   AD 47 8F 61 BD 58 51 BD  .b..,.+J.G.a.XQ.
... no encryption keys used
... no IV used for this cipher
*** CertificateVerify
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 134
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 4, 127, 139, 212, 93, 181, 170, 62, 121, 196, 243, 156, 251, 103, 206, 222, 2, 10, 84, 35, 186, 251, 144, 6, 31, 97, 135, 179, 160, 127, 204, 93, 100, 140, 74, 79 }
***
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 56
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
main, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2397
MQJE030: IOException during security flows
MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2397
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2397
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:219)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:318)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:338)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:84)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:168)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:772)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:697)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:657)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:153)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:451)
    at com.test.SSlTest.main(SSlTest.java:68)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:798)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1493)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:103)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:689)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:985)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:904)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:238)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1165)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1149)
    at com.ibm.mq.SSLHelper.configureSSLSocket(SSLHelper.java:567)
    at com.ibm.mq.SSLHelper.createSSLSocket(SSLHelper.java:150)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQInternalCommunications.createSocketConnection(MQInternalCommunications.java:2264)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications$1.run(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:157)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.initialize(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:154)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQv6InternalCommunications.<init>(MQv6InternalCommunications.java:102)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONClient.MQCONNX(MQSESSIONClient.java:1337)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSIONClient.MQCONN(MQSESSIONClient.java:1246)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:184)
    ... 10 more
```

Kindly help me....

Answer (score 5):

Your debugging process is perfect!  When setting up SSL for the first time, always test first without SSL (validates channel name spelling, listener port, etc.), then check with anonymous SSL (validates that the client can validate the QMgr's certificate) then finally check with mutually authenticated SSL.

In this case the failure is in that final step.  By this point we know that the QMgr can read it's KDB and that the client can read its trust store.  There are very few possible issues at this point and the primary ones are that the client cannot find its private key or that the QMgr cannot validate the client's key.

Since the trace shows the client is able to access its key, we know that's not the problem.  In most cases then, this points to a problem on the QMgr's side.  There are two problems typical in this case.

1. The client's key is not properly loaded into the QMgr's keystore (or perhaps a prior version of the key is loaded).
2. The QMgr does not have the current version of the KDB loaded.

Since you provided the stack trace and all other aspects of key exchange appear to be good, I'm going to take a wild guess and say the cause is #2 above.  If so then it is easily fixed.  You can use runmqsc to enter the command `REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)` which causes the QMgr to stop all SSL channels and flush the KDB from its cache.  There is an equivalent command in WMQ Explorer found by right-clicking on the QMgr.  Or just bounce the QMgr, which accomplishes the same thing.  Either of these methods result in the QMgr reloading the KDB which gives it access to the new certificate.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry that was not the issue.  Can you recreate the failure and look at the QMgr's error logs?  You should see the error at the bottom of `/var/mqm/qmgrs/<qmgrname>/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` right after the failure.

You can also dump the certificate details on the client and QMgr to verify they match and are marked as trusted in the QMgr's kdb.  You already know how to do this with keytool.  Depending on your version of WMQ server, you can use `gsk7capicmd` or `gsk8capicmd` or with WMQ v7.1 `runmqakm`.  First dump the QMgr's KDB using the `-cert -list` command, then dump the client's cert using the `-cert -details` and post the results as an update to your question.

The commands will give you help with the needed parameters.  If you want the deep details, go to https://t-rob.net/wmq/ where you will find links to the GSKit 7 and GSKit 8 manuals about halfway down the page.  The `runmqakm` command is a wrapper over GSKit 8 so if the QMgr is running WMQ v7.1 use the GSKit 8 manual.

Comment: Thanks Rob!! but I am still not able to access it.

Comment: Yeah, don't know why those are not part of the Infocenter. Glad it helped!